# Why does JSONP work with JSON-formatted data?

Tags: ajax, jsonp

There is a URL I am using in a project of mine, that is working just fine. I make a request from one web server, to a different IP address, invoking a page that outputs data in this format:

```
[{"PhoneNumber":"+123456789","Name":"Mark"},
{"PhoneNumber":"+123456789","Name":"Josh"},
{"PhoneNumber":"+123456789","Name":"Alex"},
{"PhoneNumber":"+123456789","Name":"John"},
{"PhoneNumber":"+123456789","Name":"Sean"}]
```

And I can get and process that data with a function call such as this:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: serverAddress + "/getpeople", 
    dataType: "jsonp",
    timeout: 4000,
    success: function(response) {
        for(var i in response) {
            alert(response[i].Name);
        }
    }
});
```

Here is what's confusing me. From what I've learned about JSONP so far, it isn't actually data, but is instead a function. So the response should be wrapped in a function call, such as `callback()`, and then I could implement a `function callback(data) {}` in my project to process the data.

But in this case, the data seems to be just JSON data, which I think should cause a cross-origin error to be generated? But it doesn't.

When I try to call another URL from the same server, fetching an ordinary plain text file, then I do get a cross-origin error, which complains in the console:

> Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing

But the original `getpeople` URL does not have that header either. When I examine the response headers in Firefox's document inspector, all of the headers are:

```
Connection: "close"
Content-Type: "text/html;charset=utf-8"
Date: "Mon, 5 Oct 2015 08:29:07 GMT"
Server: "ServerName/1.1.10011.2211"
```

So:

1. The data is not formatted as a JSONP callback
2. It is served from a different IP address than the web application
3. The response doesn't have a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header

Why does this work?

Comment: Have you tried the same URL but adding a `?callback=random` to the end of it?

Comment: If you mean the call to the plain-text file, yes I did just now, it still fails. As well I think it should. Why the other thing doesn't fail is what worries me.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the JSON file.